# US20100332310 - Location Based System & Method for Issuing Prizes on Mobile Devices - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, rejected, invalidation, us20100332310

Others have delivered mobile advertising using geolocation since before the patent [us20100332310](http://www.google.com/patents/US20100332310) was filed in Jun 25, 2009. Have you seen prior art before Jun 25,2009?

## [Systems and methods for advertising and distributing prizes using location-based services](http://www.google.com/patents/US20100332310)

- Publication number:   US20100332310 A1
- Publication type: Application
- Application number:   US 12/823,045
- Publication date: Dec 30, 2010
- Filing date   Jun 24, 2010
- **Priority date   Jun 25, 2009**

## Abstract

> The system and methods include delivering a prize to a mobile device based upon the geographic location of the mobile device. The system can include a registration interface for registering a plurality of mobile devices with the system and a registration interface for registering a plurality of clients with the system. A prize designation interface can associated one or more prizes with a specific geographic location. The prizes can be delivered to registered mobile devices when it is determined that the mobile devices are in the specific geographic locations associated with the prizes.

## Independent Claim 1

> A system for delivering a prize to a mobile device, the system comprising:
>   a registration interface for registering a plurality of mobile devices with the system;
>
> - a registration interface for registering a plurality of clients with the system;
> - a prize designation interface through which each of the plurality of clients can designate one or more prizes, each prize being associated with a specific geographic location;
> - a geographic location receiving device configured to receive information relating to the geographic location of the registered mobile devices; and
> - a delivery device for delivering the prize to one of the registered mobile devices when that mobile device is located within a predetermined radius of the specific geographic location associated with the delivered prize.

## Independent Claim 13

> A method for delivering a redeemable prize to a mobile device using a prize delivery system, the method comprising:
>
> - registering a plurality of mobile devices with the system;
> - registering a plurality of clients with the system;
> - associating a plurality of redeemable prizes with one or more clients, each redeemable prize being associated with a specific geographic location;
> - determining when a registered mobile device is within a predetermined radius of the specific geographic location associated with one or more of the redeemable prizes; and
> - delivering the redeemable prize associated with the specific geographic location when the registered mobile device is within the predetermined radius of the specific geographic location associated with that redeemable prize.

Have you seen prior art before Jun 25, 2009?

Comment: Hi, AskPatents is an online service in Q&A format where users help find **prior art** on **US Patent Applications** and US Patents and ask questions about the US Patent process. What you are asking is called a prior art request on Ask Patents. It requires more information to be really useful. Please see [faq] for more information about which topics are on topic for Ask Patents and feel free to resubmit. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Note that the subject Patent Application US 20100332310 has already received a **non-final rejection by the USPTO** and has subsequently gone **abandoned by the applicant**.  This can be reviewed at [Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair)

Answer (score 2):

## [WO2009014735](http://www.google.com/patents/WO2009014735A2)

### System, method and apparatus for secure multiparty located based services

- Publication date:    Jan 29, 2009
- Filing date:      Jul 23, 2008
- Priority date:   **Jul 23, 2007**

This is a good example, it discusses "distributing shares" and such, which could be considered a prize?

### Abstract

> A computer system implements a method to provide secure multiparty location based services. A user input is received from a user device of a user. The user input contains user location information. Based on the location information, a model is retrieved. The model is a constraint satisfaction problem defined by a set of variables and mapping functions. The set of variables and mapping functions are into multiple shares. Each share is distributed to one of agents in finding a solution to the constraint satisfaction problem. Once a solution is computed, a demographic profile is predicted based on the solution. The solution does not contain the user location information.

### Claim 1

> A method, comprising: receiving a user input from a user device of a user, wherein the user input contains user location information;
>
> - constructing and retrieving a model based on the user location information, wherein the model is a constraint satisfaction problem defined by a set of variables and mapping functions;
> - dividing the set of variables and mapping functions into a plurality of shares; distributing the plurality of shares to a plurality of agents, wherein each of the plurality of agents participates in finding a solution to the constraint satisfaction problem;
> - predicting a demographic profile based on the solution, wherein the solution does not contain the user location information.

This is not 100% but it proves the method and system may lack novel and is obvious. I am sure you can find code examples or online tutorials published in the field of application and server development.